# Evidences against Supersymmetry

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model

Recently, some experiments show that the supersymmetry is not realised by Nature according to the simple models that we currently have. Nevertheless, it is far from saying that the "game is over" as SUSY might be realised at an unknown energy. I would like to ask what are the experiments that could give us a clue whether SUSY assumption is wrong. Will the LHC / VLHC be able to rule it out in the future?

Comment: See this article of [Matt Strassler](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/some-speculative-theoretical-ideas-for-the-lhc/supersymmetry/where-stands-supersymmetry-122013/)

Comment: You are under a misapprehension that the "simple models we have" predict anything at definite energies , at the level the LHC experiment is now. It would have been a bonus if some new resonances had been found that could be attributed to supersymmetry, that is all.

Comment: I think this falls into the discussion category, and should be closed as such. It's hard to see what answers here could add to the already vast amount of discussion on this subject floating around the many blogs in Googlespace.

Comment: @annav You are right.
However, I believe it is correct to also say that SUSY can not be pushed to arbitrary high energy for which is spontaneously breaks.
After this certain energy scale (which depends of the model, but is never as big as $100 \ TeV$) it would no longer solve the naturalness problem of the SM, which was one of the main reason for which SUSY was invented.

My opinion is that is no superpartners are ever found below the energy scale for which SUSY is useful to solve the naturalness problem, then SUSY should be assumed as wrong.

Comment: @FedericoCarta  Well, time will show, but we have not reached those energies yet . On the other hand susy comes naturally with string theories, and a string theoretical model would be a good candidate for a theory or everything so it might be that the naturalness problems is acommodated in a different way and still have the symmetry of supersymmetry and very heavy resonances. In any case if no resonances are found as the energies grow the whole program will need a rethink.

Comment: I would like to give an example of unexpected from theory  discovery. Back in the 1960s the expectation was that the higher the mass of the resonance the larger the width. And then the J/Psi was measured with a very small width http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_particle . Nature may have surprises for us yet, coming from a variant of the plethora of models floating around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One recent result which provided certain definite constraints came not from particle physics but from molecular physics. Using cold molecules, it is possible to achieve *very* high precision measurements on properties like the [electric dipole moment of the electron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_electric_dipole_moment), which are on a par or better than the constraints provided by particle physics experiments, and beginning to bite into the territory of certain supersymmetric theories.

This is nicely explained in [this Physics World article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/nov/14/search-for-electrons-electric-dipole-moment-narrows) about the latest result, an experiment on thorium monoxide molecules performed by the ACME collaboration and reported in

> Order of Magnitude Smaller Limit on the Electric Dipole
>   Moment of the Electron. The ACME Collaboration. [*Science* 1248213, 2013-12-19](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1248213). [arXiv:1310.7534](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7534).

To borrow an image from Physics World, different supersymmetric theories predict different ranges of values for $d_e$:

[image]

The ACME result constrains it to $|d_e|<8.7\times 10^{−29}\ e\ \text{cm}$. It is therefore my impression that it does rule out, or heavily constrain, several SUSY candidates.