# Disproving SUSY

Tags: experimental-physics, supersymmetry

So I get that with SUSY theories you can always move the goalposts. By definition, it is difficult to prove. So what would it take to disprove the theory entirely? What evidence would have to arise to reach that conclusion?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93095/2451 and links therein.